# De Morgan's law optimization doesn't work

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, digital-logic, demorgans-law

I have boolean expression, which was simplified using Karnaugh's map (The first line). And then I used de Morgan's Law to make the expression suitable for using only NAND gates (The second line). But when I create a logic gate circuit it does not work properly and no matter how much I look at this circuit, I can't see where I made a mistake. And sorry for posting expression in a picture, I have no knowledge of how to transfer this expression from paper to computer. [image: Simplified expression and de Morgan's version]

[image: Logic circuit using NAND gates]

Answer (score 2):

I checked your circuit and have not been able to spot an error.
What is not working?

An alternative solution is:

```
NAND4(
  NAND3(!X0, !X1, X3), 
  NAND4(X0, X1, X4, X5), 
  NAND4(!X0, X1, !X3, !X5), 
  NAND5(X0, !X1, !X2, X3, X4))
```

The solution generated by `Logic Friday 1` is:

[[image]][1]

---

**Update:**

I entered the following expression to `Logic Friday 1`:

```
INORDER = x5 x4 x3 x2 x1 x0;
F = !(!(!x0 & !(!(!x1 x3) & !(x1 !x3 !x5))) & !(x0 & !(!(x1 x4 x5) & !(!x1 !x2 !x3 x4))));
```

The resulting `18` minterms are:
[image]

Taking `X5` as most-significant and `X0` as least-significant bit, this can be interpreted as minterm list: `2, 6, 8, 12, 17, 18, 22, 24, 28, 40, 44, 49, 51, 55, 56, 59, 60, 63`.

You can quickly convince yourself (minterm `63`) that all six inputs set to `1` lead to output `1`. Minterm `2`: All inputs other than `X1` `0` leads to output `1` as well. Something might be different with your bit ordering.

Comment: It should output 1 if all six inputs are numbers f = (4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 24, 26, 34, 35, 49, 53, 57, 61) in binary, but when I run a test, the outputs are wrong and not even close to those numbers.

Comment: And the expression before de Morgan's simplification outputs correct numbers.

Comment: @aretas_pau, I agree with Axel that you have some mistake somewhere. All Xi = 1 (63) obviously satisfies this expression as it makes X0*X1*X4*X5 = True which is enough for the whole. But the fact that you have exactly the same number of satisfying solutions suggests that you made somewhere a typo.